# How can fix NetworkOnMainThread Exception in android?

Tags: android, weather

I am trying to fetching weather information using yahoo apibut it shows me Network on main Threat Exception how may i fix it.when i try this code how may i fix this problem .i am begginer so i can't understand this error so please help me to solve this.

my activity Class is

```
   package com.exercise.AndroidYahooWeatherDOM;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.Reader;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class AndroidYahooWeatherDOMActivity extends Activity {

    TextView weather;

    class MyWeather{
        String description;
        String city;
        String region;
        String country;

        String windChill;
        String windDirection;
        String windSpeed;

        String sunrise;
        String sunset;

        String conditiontext;
        String conditiondate;

        public String toString(){

            return "\n- " + description + " -\n\n"
                + "city: " + city + "\n"
                + "region: " + region + "\n"
                + "country: " + country + "\n\n"

                + "Wind\n"
                + "chill: " + windChill + "\n"
                + "direction: " + windDirection + "\n"
                + "speed: " + windSpeed + "\n\n"

                + "Sunrise: " + sunrise + "\n"
                + "Sunset: " + sunset + "\n\n"

                + "Condition: " + conditiontext + "\n"
                + conditiondate +"\n";

        }
    }

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        weather = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.weather);


        String weatherString = QueryYahooWeather();
        Document weatherDoc = convertStringToDocument(weatherString);

        MyWeather weatherResult = parseWeather(weatherDoc);
        weather.setText(weatherResult.toString());
    }

    private MyWeather parseWeather(Document srcDoc){

        MyWeather myWeather = new MyWeather();

        //<description>Yahoo! Weather for New York, NY</description>
        myWeather.description = srcDoc.getElementsByTagName("description")
                .item(0)
                .getTextContent();

        //<yweather:location city="New York" region="NY" country="United States"/>
        Node locationNode = srcDoc.getElementsByTagName("yweather:location").item(0);
        myWeather.city = locationNode.getAttributes()
                .getNamedItem("city")
                .getNodeValue()
                .toString();
        myWeather.region = locationNode.getAttributes()
                .getNamedItem("region")
                .getNodeValue()
                .toString();
        myWeather.country = locationNode.getAttributes()
                .getNamedItem("country")
                .getNodeValue()
                .toString();

        //<yweather:wind chill="60" direction="0" speed="0"/>
        Node windNode = srcDoc.getElementsByTagName("yweather:wind").item(0);
        myWeather.windChill = windNode.getAttributes()
                .getNamedItem("chill")
                .getNodeValue()
                .toString();
        myWeather.windDirection = windNode.getAttributes()
                .getNamedItem("direction")
                .getNodeValue()
                .toString();
        myWeather.windSpeed = windNode.getAttributes()
                .getNamedItem("speed")
                .getNodeValue()
                .toString();

        //<yweather:astronomy sunrise="6:52 am" sunset="7:10 pm"/>
        Node astronomyNode = srcDoc.getElementsByTagName("yweather:astronomy").item(0);
        myWeather.sunrise = astronomyNode.getAttributes()
                .getNamedItem("sunrise")
                .getNodeValue()
                .toString();
        myWeather.sunset = astronomyNode.getAttributes()
                .getNamedItem("sunset")
                .getNodeValue()
                .toString();

        //<yweather:condition text="Fair" code="33" temp="60" date="Fri, 23 Mar 2012 8:49 pm EDT"/>
        Node conditionNode = srcDoc.getElementsByTagName("yweather:condition").item(0);
        myWeather.conditiontext = conditionNode.getAttributes()
                .getNamedItem("text")
                .getNodeValue()
                .toString();
        myWeather.conditiondate = conditionNode.getAttributes()
                .getNamedItem("date")
                .getNodeValue()
                .toString();

        return myWeather;
    }

    private Document convertStringToDocument(String src){
        Document dest = null;

        DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory =
                DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder parser;

        try {
            parser = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
            dest = parser.parse(new ByteArrayInputStream(src.getBytes()));
        } catch (ParserConfigurationException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(AndroidYahooWeatherDOMActivity.this, 
                    e1.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } catch (SAXException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(AndroidYahooWeatherDOMActivity.this, 
                    e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(AndroidYahooWeatherDOMActivity.this, 
                    e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        return dest;
    }

    private String QueryYahooWeather(){

        String qResult = "";
        String queryString = "http://weather.yahooapis.com/forecastrss?w=2459115";

        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(queryString);

        try {
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpClient.execute(httpGet).getEntity();

            if (httpEntity != null){
                InputStream inputStream = httpEntity.getContent();
                Reader in = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
                BufferedReader bufferedreader = new BufferedReader(in);
                StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

                String stringReadLine = null;

                while ((stringReadLine = bufferedreader.readLine()) != null) {
                    stringBuilder.append(stringReadLine + "\n");    
                }

                qResult = stringBuilder.toString(); 
            }

        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(AndroidYahooWeatherDOMActivity.this, 
                    e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(AndroidYahooWeatherDOMActivity.this, 
                    e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        return qResult;
    }
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml is

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.exercise.AndroidYahooWeatherDOM"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            android:name=".AndroidYahooWeatherDOMActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: dont do a network call from the main thread... then its fixed

Comment: Use the AsyncTask class

Comment: Please see at single time my code

Answer (score 0):

call `QueryYahooWeather()` in `AsyncTask`
You should read ["Perform Network Operations on a Separate Thread"](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/connecting.html#AsyncTask)